# Special characters not rendering correctly with Quarto in R

Tags: r, encoding, markdown, knitr, quarto

I am producing a report with R using quarto markdown. The output's format is HTML, and I was using ISO8859-1 encoding and it was rendering special characters (ã, ç, é, º, ª etc) fine. However, as I updated the report, it stopped rendering these characters correctly. This is my header as of now:

```yaml
---
title: 'Nota Técnica - Índice Socioeconômico dos Estudantes'
author: 'CAEd'
format: 
  html:
    encoding: 'ISO8859-1'
    theme: style.css
editor: visual
lang: pt
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---
```

I've already tried changing the encoding argument's position as well, with no success:

```yaml
---
title: 'Nota Técnica - Índice Socioeconômico dos Estudantes'
author: 'CAEd'
format: 
  html:
    theme: style.css
editor: visual
lang: pt
encoding: 'ISO8859-1'
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---
```

I have tried different encoding options (LATIN-1, UTF-8, WINDOWS-1252) and had no success as well.

Comment: Don’t use legacy code page encodings. **Use UTF-8.** In particular, the ISO-8859-1 simply *does not contain special characters* so you cannot use it here. The fact that it ever worked for you was an accident based on a historical bug in browsers which mis-interpret this encoding. But, being a bug, this behaviour should obviously not be relied on. In addition, there’s *another* bug here because the charset name is actually `ISO-8859-1` (note the extra dash), although apparently some browsers also accept `ISO8859-1`.

Comment: Thank you! Had to change the encoding on the yaml header and on R's default saving encoding, but it worked.